# $h(\frac{z}{4^{n}})=0$ $\forall z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\ h(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $h: \mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $h(\frac{z}{4^{n}})=0$ $\forall z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\ h(x)=0$

What I thought is to show "$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall\epsilon>0,\exists z,\ \exists n$, such that $|x-\frac{z}{4^{n}}|<\epsilon$" first, i.e. $x-\epsilon<\frac{z}{4^{n}}<x+\epsilon$ for some $z$ and $n$.

I have no idea how to prove the claim, and then how to use this to show that $h(x)=0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Does anyone could help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any real number $y$ and $\delta > 0$, show that you can find integers $z$ and $n > 0$ so that $|z/4^n - y| < \delta$. If you want to go back to basics to do this, use the Archimedes principle. The rest will follow by continuity if you trace out the definition of continuity.

Comment: That's the problem, if there is just only one variable, I can just solve the inequality, but there are two variables z and n are dependent, how can I find them?